# r + dplyr filtering out time series

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data that looks at a group of people and the fruits they eat over time. I want to use dplyr to look at each individual person up until they eat a banana and summarise all the fruits they ate *up until they eat their first banana*.

data:

```
data <-  structure(list(user = c(1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 
    1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 9584L, 9584L, 9584L, 
    9584L, 9584L, 9584L, 9584L, 9584L, 9584L, 4758L, 4758L, 4758L, 
    4758L, 4758L, 4758L), site = structure(c(1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 
    5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("apple", "banana", "lemon", 
    "lime", "orange", "pear"), class = "factor"), time = c(1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), int = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("banana", 
    "other"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("user", "site", "time", 
    "int"), row.names = c(NA, -27L), class = "data.frame")
```

My initial thought would be to group the data to find the first instance of each user eating a banana:

```
data <- data %>% transform(var = ifelse(site=="banana", 'banana','other'))

data_ban <- data %>% 
    filter(var=='banana') %>% 
    group_by(user, var, time) %>%
    group_by(user) %>%
    summarise(first_banana = min(time))
```

But now I'm stuck on how to actually apply this back to the original "data" dataframe, and set a filter that says: for each user, only include data up until the time given in "data_ban". Any ideas?

Comment: Can you also post the expected output.  May be `data %>% group_by(user) %>% slice(1:(which(int=='banana')[1L]))`

Comment: @akrun, what you posted gives the expected output. What's the difference between [1L] and the [1] that Romain posted below?

Comment: It is just to get an integer index instead of numeric index.  1L coerce to integer (supposedly faster)

Comment: If you need only the row that is max for time `data %>% group_by(user) %>% slice(which.max(time[seq(which(int=='banana')[1L])]))` (assuming that `time` is not ordered.  Otherwise, just `which(int=='banana')[1L]` would get the last row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try `slice`

```
data %>%
     group_by(user) %>% 
     slice(1:(which(int=='banana')[1L]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this: grouping by `user` and filtering `time` lower than the first time they eat a banana.

```
> data %>% group_by(user) %>% filter( time <= which(site=="banana")[1] )
Source: local data frame [17 x 4]
Groups: user

   user   site time    int
1  1234  apple    1  other
2  1234   pear    2  other
3  1234  apple    3  other
4  1234  apple    4  other
5  1234   pear    5  other
6  1234 orange    6  other
7  1234 orange    7  other
8  1234  lemon    8  other
9  1234   lime    9  other
10 1234  apple   10  other
11 1234 banana   11 banana
12 9584  apple    1  other
13 9584   pear    2  other
14 9584 orange    3  other
15 9584 orange    4  other
16 9584  lemon    5  other
17 9584 banana    6 banana
```

Otherwise perhaps an `anti_join`.

Comment: I like this solution! My only question is: What does the vector call ([1]) do? I found that with it, I'm missing User 4758 but removing it yields the same results, just with that user addedin..

Comment: ... capturing the *first* time the user eats a banana