# r + keeping first observation of time series group

Tags: r, dplyr

A follow-up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31053597/r-dplyr-filtering-out-time-series) (I want to keep the threads separate): I want to look at each user and the fruits they ate. But I'm only interested in the *first* time they eat a fruit. From there, I want to rank order the fruits eaten by time.

Some data:

```
set.seed(1234)
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(
    user = sample(c("1234","9876","4567"), 30, replace = TRUE),
    fruit = sample(c("banana","apple","pear","lemon"), 30, replace = TRUE),
    date = rep(seq(as.Date("2010-02-01"), length=10, by = "1 day"),3))

data <- data %>% arrange(user, date)
```

In this case, you can see that, for example, User 1234 ate a banana on 2010-02-01, then again on 02-03, 02-04, and 02-05.

```
   user  fruit       date
1  1234 banana 2010-02-01
2  1234  lemon 2010-02-02
3  1234 banana 2010-02-03
4  1234  apple 2010-02-03
5  1234  lemon 2010-02-03
6  1234 banana 2010-02-04
7  1234 banana 2010-02-05
```

I don't want to change anything about the relative order of fruits by time, but I do want to remove all subsequent instances of "banana" after the first one (and likewise with every other fruit).

for User 1234 in this case, I'm looking for:

```
   user  fruit       date
1  1234 banana 2010-02-01
2  1234  lemon 2010-02-02
4  1234  apple 2010-02-03
```

One way I can think of going about this is arranging the dataframe by user > fruit > date, then keeping only the first unique observation of "fruit" by the user grouping. I'm getting hung up on how exactly to do that in dplyr. Any thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `distinct(data, user, fruit)`?

Comment: @docendodiscimus That would make a good answer. Beats my instinct of `data %>% group_by(user,fruit) %>% slice(1)` for conciseness and efficiency

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a an approach using the `duplicated` function.

```
data %>%
group_by(user) %>%
filter(!duplicated(fruit))
#    user  fruit       date
# 1  1234  apple 2010-02-01
# 2  1234 banana 2010-02-01
# 3  1234   pear 2010-02-03
# 4  1234  lemon 2010-02-10
# 5  4567   pear 2010-02-01
# 6  4567 banana 2010-02-05
# 7  4567  lemon 2010-02-08
# 8  9876  apple 2010-02-02
# 9  9876   pear 2010-02-02
# 10 9876  lemon 2010-02-06
```

Comment: I guess my general question here is: By removing duplicates, will dplyr *always* refer to the first instance? So the data frame always has to be sorted by timestamp first, right?

Comment: @aaronwolen has an answer that is order agnostic

Comment: You can add `arrange(date)` in your solution.

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` solution would involve grouping by the user and fruit variables and filtering for rows with the lowest ranked date:

```
data %>%
  group_by(user, fruit) %>%
  filter(row_number(date) == 1)
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it *The* `dplyr` solution. A much more efficient `dplyr` solution was already mentioned in comments.

Comment: Thanks, hadn't seen that. I'd still lean toward this approach since it doesn't assume the rows have been ordered by date (although I realize they are in OP's question).

Comment: Your approach makes the same assumption. Either way, when posting a solution, on a site like SO, your solution will be never *The* solution, rather *one possible* solution.

Comment: No, it doesn't make the same assumption; `row_number()` returns the rank of `date`. But I did update my answer to incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: Yep, it seems like you are right regarding `row_number`. I stand corrected.